# bootstrap-datetimepicker cannot select date

Tags: node.js, pug, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am new to NodeJS and AngularJS. I am using bootstrap datetimepicker (https://github.com/zhaber/datetimepicker). The example I am following is this one http://plnkr.co/edit/GIaEpg?p=preview

When I create new application and put it in plain HTML file, it works fine. But when I try to integrate it with my application that is using jade template, it cannot select the date in datetimepicker. Rest of the buttons inside date time picker works but only selecting date is not working.

Here is my jade code

```
.div(id='datetimepicker1', ng-controller='DateTimePickerDemoCtrl')
  datetimepicker(min-date='minDate', show-weeks='showWeeks', hour-step='hourStep', minute-step='minuteStep', ng-model='date', show-meridian='showMeridian', date-format='dd-MMM-yyyy', date-options='dateOptions', date-disabled='disabled(date, mode)', showMinutes='true')
```

I am using bootstrap 3.0.0 and JQuery 1.10.2

In following image, I clicked on a date, it gets highlighted but in the box it is not updated.

There is no error in chrome developer tool

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I don't see any `.div(id='datetimepicker1'` conainer in your plnkr example, but in your jade, so remove it and you get the same HTMl result

Comment: @timaschew! Thanks for the reply. I added that 'id' tag when it was not working. I have removed it now, and there is no difference in result :(

Comment: there is no difference and it still doesn't work? If yes, there is an other diff in your code / environments expect Jade & HTML

Comment: Yes. It still does not work. You are right about Jade and HTML difference. I also feel that somehow it is unable to work with Jade Template. Trying to figure out why!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was my bad. It was due to rc2 version of angular.js. In my HTML application I was using latest version of angular.js. I updated that to version 1.2.10 and now it works fine.

It had nothing to do with Jade Template or HTML...